# How to decrypt attachments embedded in an e-mail with gpg?

Tags: linux, email, gpg

When I decrypt an e-mail received from Gmail, I get the attachment as a base64 encoded string in the body of the decrypted e-mail.

I have to then manually extract the base64 string and decode it with base64 -d or similar to actually obtain the attachment file.

I'm surprised I can't find an argument to gpg that decrypts and base64 decodes any found attachments into separate files for me. What is a convenient way to do this?

Comment: I think that you'd better worry about why your MUA give you the attachment as base64 string....
The convinient way depends, IMHO, on the MUA you use, so please, update your question !

Comment: @binarym Thanks, updated. MUA is Gmail.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Protonmail also encrypted the attachments, which looks similar to this:

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Content-Type: text/html
Version: ProtonMail

wcBMA9huJ3ednol8AQf9GkIDfBmoLhXbkfQ/xiH/IA6c5FSXS5t0ybrKL/c0
... base 64 ...
PO/ZPcImGYDYUgd1VkItf9xdnFo02c9OF+8=
=r9ZO
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----

--b1_UtzHbBo7cr7IHemm3M2xGQe8Ak73bka7W7I3ZHMX6c
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="=?utf-8?Q?name.jpg.pgp?="
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="=?utf-8?Q?name.jpg.pgp?="

wcBMA9huJ3ednol8AQf+OX4BrthHHn10wHpniO8+qt4pDFpOZiqNOawF1sDeWeu5mmimF8hsma5V
... long base64 ...
bm//YnWeec1rBfdTbu2eCf4Z7snf2Q==
```

The first base64 encoded message is the email content, the second one is the attachment I was looking for. To decrypt it, I've padded the attachments base64 with `-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----` and `-----END PGP MESSAGE-----` like this:

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
wcBMA9huJ3ednol8AQf+OX4BrthHHn10wHpniO8+qt4pDFpOZiqNOawF1sDeWeu5mmimF8hsma5V
... long base64 ...
bm//YnWeec1rBfdTbu2eCf4Z7snf2Q==
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

Then save this to a new file and decrypt it with `gpg -o name.jpg -d encrypted_attachment.txt`.

This is inconvenient, but the process can be automated by a script (e.g., find all attachments in the file, pad them as a PGP MESSAGE block, write them to separate files, then decrypt them).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a convenient way to do this directly with GPG however you can decrypt, then import the decrypted HTML mail into Thunderbird and it will correctly parse out the base64 encoded attachments, allowing you to deal with them as normal.

For folks looking for manual instructions, they're below.

The MIME encoded email will have attachments embedded within the email file. Those MIME encoded attachments are base64 encoded. Here's an example:

```
-----------------------280fe25f5480076f6dcc4a82dc971dc5
Content-Type: application/pgp-keys; filename="textfile.txt - email@email.com - textfile.txt"; name="textfile - email@email.com - textfile.txt"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="textfile - email@email.com - textfile.txt"; name="textfile - email@email.com - textfile.txt"
    
dGhpcyBpcyB0aGUgYmFzZTY0IGVuY29kZWQgdGV4dAo=
-----------------------280fe25f5480076f6dcc4a82dc971dc5--
```

This marks the start of the attachment details:

```
-----------------------280fe25f5480076f6dcc4a82dc971dc5
```

and this marks the end (note the two extra `--` on the end):

```
-----------------------280fe25f5480076f6dcc4a82dc971dc5--
```

The first few lines are metadata. The useful part is this:

```
dGhpcyBpcyB0aGUgYmFzZTY0IGVuY29kZWQgdGV4dAo=
```

You can copy that and save it out to `textfile.txt` then run the following to see what it actually says:

```bsh
base64 -d textfile.txt
```

If it's a binary file like an image or similar, redirect the output to your final filename e.g.

```bsh
base64 -d tempfilename.base64 > picture.jpg
```